# How to get buffering percent of VideoView on Android

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

My code as below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

I use VideoView to play a stream video.
The video is a VideoView.
And I want to get the buffering percent like setOnBufferingUpdateListener in MediaPlayer.

```
MediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        //buffering is percent
    }
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `VideoView` does not provide access to its wrapped `MediaPlayer` or a way to set a callback for buffering progress, although it uses both internally. The way I see it, you could either poll the value by repeatedly calling `getBufferPercentage()` (not ideal), or use reflection to get ahold of the `MediaPlayer` instance and register your own listener (also not ideal).

Comment: I added a Thread that calls getBufferPercentage() every second, but the percentage returned is really weird. It doesn't keep increasing, sometimes it decreases and never goes over a few units %. The same thread works on other the exoplayer, so the calls are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this method for your VideoView:

```
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

mp is the MediaPlayer the update pertains to
percent is the percentage (0-100) of the content that has been buffered or played thus far.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html)

You can add a progressbar before u start loading the Video, and then keep updating it inside this method.
And once the buffering is complete (in onPreparedListener), just dismiss the progressbar.

Comment: But I don't need progressbar, I only need the percent number.

Comment: This is incorrect. Implementing onBufferingUpdate in a subclassed VideoView does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

let your **activity implement**

**OnBufferingUpdateListener** ...

and then you get:

```
  @Override
  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

  }
```

**:=) good luck**

Comment: I have implemented  it in my activity itself, but it does not call back again.

Comment: I have asked as separate question in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029597/how-to-startplay-video-once-buffer-reaches-20-in-android-video-view

Comment: okay, sorry currently not into this topic, probably there is some way to setup the buffer for auto playing at some %. good luck.

Comment: No actually i have added the call back function for the buffer listener in that code but it's not called that's my issues ... i know the way to start play after some percentage.