# Android: how to know how many percent of media player loaded from url?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();                    
     } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     mediaPlayer.start();
```

> this is my mediaplayer for play voice from url

Comment: Take a look at the various callbacks: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#callbacks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get buffering percent of VideoView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278873/how-to-get-buffering-percent-of-videoview-on-android)

Comment: @OmarShawky `MediaPlayer` is not `VideoView`

Comment: well in the question he did mention existence of a method to override named `onBufferingUpdate `, which you can read about here : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener

Answer (score 0):

You can have in a Thread or Coroutine Job the following code:

```kotlin
while(player.isRunning) {
  
  val percentage = (player.currentPosition / player.duration.toFloat())
  ...
}
```